# How do I properly replace a method in python that dispatches to a delegate while maintaining method arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm leveraging an async framework that serializes/deserializes data from the wire returning the deserialized result via a Future.

The problem I have is that there are some RPC calls that don't have a return value.  If I return `None` from the deserialization result, the async framework chokes thinking there was a problem with the deserialization process.

To work around this, I've updated the deserializer to return a token representing no return value.  This has gotten me further, but I still need to post-process the future return value to check for this token, and if present, return None.

I'm looking for a clean way to deal with this situation.  I could create a delegate class that wraps the future and overrides all of the methods and dispatch/post-process as needed, but this feels overly verbose.

Another attempt is the following:

```
 def wrap_future(self, delegate):
    orig_result = delegate.result
    delegate.result = lambda: self.post_process(orig_result.__call__())
    return delegate
```

This works for the simple case, but as Future can accept arguments, I'm not quite sure how to capture and pass said arguments.

This leaves me wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Why `orig_result.__call__()` and not just `orig_result()`? Also: am I mistaken or you just want `lambda *args, **kwargs: self.post_process(orig_result(*args, **kwargs))`? This accomodates every possible signature for the `orig_result` call.

Comment: Inexperience mostly :).  Thanks, that did the trick!